# How to display value from database in table

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple html table within PHP. Here is my code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="chart">
        <h2>Files Uploaded to Knowledge Base</h2>
        <table id="data-table" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">


        <tr id=header>
                <td>Users</td>
                <td id=center>Project Files</td>
                <td id=center>Process Files</td>
                <td id=center>System Files</td>
                <td id=center>Total Files</td>
        </tr>   

                    <?php

                    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/project/');
                    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                    $pos = 15;
                    $file = substr("$filename", +$pos); 

                    $lenght = strlen($file);
                    $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                    $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);
                    if($file1 != '.DS_Store'){

                        $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM Project WHERE location = '$file'");

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                            $occurance1 = $row['uploader'];
                            $array1[] = $occurance1; 
                            }
                        }                           
                    }




                    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/process/');
                    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                    $pos = 15;
                    $file = substr("$filename", +$pos);                         
                    $lenght = strlen($file);
                    $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                    $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);

                    if($file != '.DS_Store'){

                        $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM Process WHERE processlocation = '$file'");

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                            $occurance2 = $row['uploader'];
                            $array2[] = $occurance2; 
                            }
                        }                           
                    }

                    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('upload/system/');
                    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {

                    $pos = 14;
                    $file = substr("$filename", +$pos);                         
                    $lenght = strlen($file);
                    $pos = strpos($file, "/");
                    $file = substr("$file",0,$pos);
                    if($file != '.DS_Store'){

                        $serverfiles = mysql_query("SELECT uploader FROM System WHERE location = '$file'");

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverfiles)) {
                            $occurance3 = $row['uploader'];
                            $array3[] = $occurance3; 
                            }
                        }                           
                    }

                    $table_rows = array();
                    $counter = 0;
                    $uploader = mysql_query("Select username from members");
                    while($Load = mysql_fetch_array($uploader)){
                    $value = $Load['username'];

                    $tmp = array_count_values($array1);
                    $cnt = $tmp[$value];

                    $tmp2 = array_count_values($array2);
                    $cnt2 = $tmp2[$value];

                    $tmp3 = array_count_values($array3);
                    $cnt3 = $tmp3[$value];

                    $total = $cnt + $cnt2 + $cnt3;

                    //putting the values into array
                    $counter++;
                    $table_rows[$counter] = array();
                    $table_rows[$counter]['username'] = $value;
                    $table_rows[$counter]['project'] = $cnt;
                    $table_rows[$counter]['process'] = $cnt2;
                    $table_rows[$counter]['system'] = $cnt3;
                    $table_rows[$counter]['total'] = $total;
                    }

                    //function to sort the highest total value
                    function cmp_rows($a,$b) {
                    if ($a['total'] == $b['total']) {
                    return 0;
                    }
                    return ($a['total'] > $b['total']) ? -1 : 1;
                    }

                    usort($table_rows, 'cmp_rows');

                    //loop that prints values
                    foreach($table_rows as $row) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>{$row['username']}</td>";
                    echo"<td id=center>{$row['project']}</td>";
                    echo"<td id=center>{$row['process']}</td>";
                    echo "<td id=center>{$row['system']}</td>";
                    echo "<td id=center>{$row['total']}</td>";
                    }


                    ?>

        </table>

   </div>

    </body></html>
```

The users are populated from a database table. The file figures are populated by reading and counting the amount of files in the directory. The table is sorted by highest first. I would also like to display values from the column 'accessDate' from the members table for each member but I'm not sure how to do this. It doesn't work like the other values above..

I do not know how to do this. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Is "accessDate" stored as a UNIX timestamp or what?

Comment: It's a timestamp of when the user accesses the main page of the site. Its a datatime type in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get a formatted date into your table, something like this will do it (- see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format for date formatting in MySQL)

```
...
//MySQL can format the date for you
$uploader = mysql_query(
    "Select username, DATE_FORMAT(accessDate,'%m %d, %Y') formatted_date from members");
while($Load = mysql_fetch_array($uploader))
{
...
    //putting the values into array
    $counter++;
    $table_rows[$counter] = array();
    $table_rows[$counter]['date'] = $Load['formatted_date'];
    $table_rows[$counter]['username'] = $value;
...
}
...
foreach($table_rows as $row)
{
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$row['username']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row['date']}</td>";
...
}
...
```